# MFC: what would be the regex to check if a character is unicode or not?

Tags: regex, mfc, visual-c++

I'm trying to use windows' API IsTextUnicode to check if a character input is unicode or not, but is sort of buggy. I figured, it might be better using a regex. However, I'm new to constructing regular expressions. What would be the regex to check if a character is unicode or not?

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "is sort of buggy"?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2005/01/30/363308.aspx for an extensive discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends what you mean by ‘Unicode’. As the answers so far say, pretty much any character “is Unicode”.

Windows abuses the term ‘Unicode’ to mean the UTF-16LE encoding that the Win32 API uses internally. You can detect UTF-16 by looking for the Byte Order Mark at the front, bytes `FF FE` for UTF-16LE (or `FE FF` for UTF-16BE). It's possible to have UTF-16 text that is not marked with a BOM, but that's quite bad news as you can only detect it by pure guesswork.

Pure guesswork is what the `IsTextUnicode` function is all about. It looks at the input bytes and, by seeing how often common patterns turn up in it, guesses how likely it is that the bytes represent UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE-encoded characters. Since every sequence of bytes is potentially a valid encoding of characters(*), you might imagine this isn't very predictable or reliable. And you'd be right.

See Windows i18n guru Michael Kaplan's [description](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/30/363308.aspx) of `IsTextUnicode` and why it's probably not a good idea.

In general you would want a more predictable way of guessing what encoding a set of bytes represents. You could try:

- if it begins `FE FF`, it's UTF-16LE, what Windows thinks of as ‘Unicode’;
- if it begins `FF FE`, it's UTF-16BE, what Windows equally-misleadingly calls ‘reverse’ Unicode;
- otherwise check the whole string for invalid UTF-8 sequences. If there are none, it's probably UTF-8 (or just ASCII);
- otherwise try the system default codepage.

(*: actually not quite true. Apart from the never-a-characters like U+FFFF, there are also many sequences of UTF-16 code units that aren't valid characters, thanks to the ‘surrogates’ approach to encoding characters outside the 16-bit range. However `IsTextUnicode` doesn't know about those anyway, as it predates the astral planes.)

Comment: Quibble: UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE are separate encodings from UTF-16 that do not use BOM's; the endianness is indicated solely by the name.  What MS calls "Unicode" is actually UTF-16 (little-endian, with BOM).

Answer (score 1):

Every character you'll encounter is part of Unicode. For instance, latin `'a'` is `U+0061`. This is especially true on Windows, which natievely uses Unicode and UTF-16 encoding.

The Microsoft function `IsTextUnicode` is named rather unfortunately. It could more accurately be described as `GuessTextEncodingFromRawBytes()`. I suspect that your real problem is not the interpretation of raw bytes, since you already know it's one character.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up two different concepts. A character and its encoding are not the same. Some characters (like `A`) are encoded identically in ASCII or latin-1 and UTF-8, some aren't, some can only be encoded in UTF-8 etc.

`IsTextUnicode()` tries to guess the encoding from a stream of raw bytes.

If, on the other hand, you already have a character representation, and you wish to find out whether it can be natively expressed as ASCII or latin-1 or some other encoding, then you could indeed look at the character range (`[\u0000-\u007F]` for ASCII).

Lastly, there are some invalid codes (like `\uFFFE`) which are possible bytes representations that are not allowed as Unicode characters. But I don't think this is what you're looking for.